# TailwindCSS not updating in browser after modifying classes

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm running Tailwind with React but in order for me to see changes that I make to classNames I have to restart the server and run `npm run start` again to see the updates.
Is there something I need to change in my scripts so that the browser updates without having to restart the server.

###### package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm run build:css && react-scripts start",
  "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "build:css": "postcss src/CSS/tailwind.scss -o src/CSS/index.scss "
}
```

###### tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = { 
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './src/**/*'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

###### postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

I did that with `npm-run-all` but it didn't work. Suggest me another way?

Comment: Please show tailwind and postcss configs. Are you sure that the class you change has an effect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwindcss Not Updating In Browser after Class Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74691831/tailwindcss-not-updating-in-browser-after-class-change)

Answer (score 0):

You generated the react project from Create React App, right? Why not follow this [process](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)? postcss does everything for you to update the latest implementation.